# C++ - How to check if array of unsigned int is empty or not

Tags: c++

I have this:

```
std::uint32_t data[6];
std::map<std::string, std::variant<int, float, std::string, std::uint32_t> map_;

map_["data0"] = data[0] ? data[0] : 0;
map_["data1"] = data[1] ? data[1] : 0;
map_["data2"] = data[2] ? data[2] : 0;
map_["data3"] = data[3] ? data[3] : 0;
map_["data4"] = data[4] ? data[4] : 0;
map_["data5"] = data[5] ? data[5] : 0;
```

The idea of `map_["data0"] = data[0] ? data[0] : 0;` is to see if there is any value already set in `data[0]`if not to set `0`.

However this does not work properly. Even if `data[0]` is not set it does not return '0'.

Any idea how can I check the array at specific index if the `std::uint32_t` is "initilized" or set ?

Comment: Even if reading an uninitialized object didn't have undefined behaviour, it would be impossible to tell the difference between "a zero created by initalization" and "a zero that happened by chance".

Comment: Just use `std::array<std::uint32_t,6> data{}` and it will create a 0 initialized array for you.  And even though not perfect, std;:array has more advantages over "C" style arrays so I advise you start using it.

Comment: In other words : "C++" will never initialize variables if you don't ask for it. Your data[6] will be an array of unititialized ints. You might consider std::optional<int> if it is really important to know if a value has ever been assigned to an integer.

Comment: With `std::uint32_t data[6]{}`, you can just do `map_["data0"] = data[0];`.

Comment: An integer is "truth-y" if it's not zero. Thus, `data[0] ? data[0] : 0` is equivalent to `data[0]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to check if an integer type is initialized or not. An integer is not a pointer, and it is not pointer-like, it is not nullable. An uninitialized integer has an indeterminate value which cannot be inspected and which is distinct from the concept of null.

You need to track whether or not each element has a value yourself somehow.

Possible solutions include :

- Using a sentinel value. For example, you could decide that the
  maximum representable value means "no value" and initialized all
  elements to that value.
- Using flags. You could create another array of `bool` or a
  `std::bitset` to track which element has a value.
- Using a different type which can encode more information, such as
  `std::optional<std::uint32_t> data[6];`.

Comment: Using a Sentinel based solution could be better for performance wise. On the other hand I find the optional based approach more idiomatic.

Comment: How can I check if optional is set or not ?

Comment: @Venelin You don't need to. Your current code should work. It has a [`operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool) member function that does check for the existence of a value.

Comment: @Venelin See [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). You could use `if(data[0])` or `data[0].has_value();`. Or in your case, you could also use `data[0].value_or(0);` to get the value, or a default of 0 if it has no value.

Comment: Actaully it gives me this error: `candidate template ignored: requirement '18446744073709551615UL < sizeof...(_Types)' was not satisfied [with _Tp = std::optional<uint32>]` on this line `map_["data0"] = data[0] ? data[0] : 0;`

Comment: `map_["data0"] = data[0].value_or(0);`.

Comment: This solved the issue but created another. I have it described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76219723/c-call-to-implicitly-deleted-default-constructor

Comment: @Venelin The solution provided in by this answer is not applicable to the problem described in the linked question, because `union` changes everything. The overall approach you show in your new question seems to be using `union` to perform type punning, and it looks like your intention was to zero out values from the array which aren't used by the active `union` member, both of which are not supported by C++. Use `std::variant` instead, and provide proper serialization functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how can I check the array at specific index if the `std::uint32_t` is "initilized" or set ?

Your code has undefined behavior (uninitialized value). This makes code invalid and you can't recover form this. So instead handling this in code, configure your compiler to detect all warnings and threat them as errors (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`):

https://godbolt.org/z/Mox4co7df

There are other tools which can detect common errors in C++ code: Address Sanitizer, Undefined Behavior Sanitizer (there are more sanitizers) (`-fsanitize=address,undefined`). There are also some static analysis tools: cpplint, clang-analyzer, ... .

The more tools you will setup for your project then better. You will find mistakes done in code faster and automatically.